# How to do multiple domains applied to ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, multiple-domains

I'ved create a ruby on rails app.

And now I have several customers that want a white-label app for themselves.

Currently, it is on nginx server + puma (ruby on rails).

Is it possible to have different domains for the same Ruby On Rails app ? How do I accomplish such thing ?

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
```

NOTE: PLEASE ANSWER SINCERELY AND CORRECTLY.

Each domain have a customizable look and feel. It is still using a single rails app. That is what we are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You just have configure your DNS.

After that, you can get the domain in your rails app with `request.host` and apply your style based on this.

Comment: yeah but how to i be more specific about where the domains are routed to ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can apply your style based on request.host

Comment: thanks i think this is what im looking for. let me verify. thanks.